# Do I need to use strong params if action doesn't affect models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm 80% sure the answer is "no", but I need affirmation.

### Case scenario

For controller looking like this:

```
class CatController < ApplicationController
  def search_cats
    render json: HTTPClient.new.get('https://api.example.com', search_cats_params)
  end

  private

  def search_cats_params
    params.permit(:breed, :ownership, :vaccination, foo: [ :bar, :baz ])
  end
end
```

Would it be safe to just pass the params forward like this?

```
class CatController < ApplicationController
  def search_cats
    render json: HTTPClient.new.get('https://api.example.com', params.to_h)
  end
end
```

Wouldn't user be able to flood server with enormous query, for example?

Documentation only says strong params exist to protect models from malicious mass assignment.

https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: IMO it would still be best to limit what is sent to a third party API, especially if you pay to use the API or the API has any kind of acceptable use policy. Passing params straight through could result in you being banned from the API because you have 1 malicious user that ruins it for you and everyone else.

Comment: internet is scary place i always prefer to use strong params in my controllers.